# Estimating possible # of actors in Scala

Tags: scala, multiprocessing, actor

How can I estimate the number of actors that a Scala program can handle?

For context, I'm contemplating what is essentially a neural net that will be creating and forgetting cells at a high rate.  I'm contemplating making each cell an actor, but there will be millions of them.  I'm trying to decide whether this design is worth pursuing, but can't estimate the limits of number of actors.  My intent is that it should totally run on one system, so distributed limits don't apply.

For that matter, I haven't definitely settled on Scala, if there's some better choice, but the cells *do* have state, as in, e.g., their connections to other cells, the weights of the connections, etc.  Though this COULD be done as "Each cell is final.  Changes mean replacing the current cell with a new one bearing the same id#."

P.S.:  I don't know Scala.  I'm considering picking it up to do this project.  I'm also considering lots of other alternatives, including Java, Object Pascal and Ada.  But actors *seem* a better map to what I'm after than thread-pools (and Java can't handle enough threads to make a thread/cell design feasible.

P.S.:  At all times, most of the actors will be quiescent, but there wil need to be a way of cycling through the entire collection of them.  If there isn't one built into the language, then this can be managed via first/next links within each cell.  (Both links are needed, to allow cells in the middle to be extracted for release.)

Comment: If you haven't already done so, I would recommend looking in Akka for using actors in scala/java instead of using scala actors. It also provides much more than just actors. If you are interested in broadcasting to all child actors of an actor or system, there are ways to use a list of all children of an actor. For example, using context.children inside of an actor reference or using an ActorSelection: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/addressing.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a neural net simulation, the real question is how much of the computational effort will be spent communicating, and how much will be spent computing something within a cell?  If most of the effort is in communication then actors are perhaps a good choice for correctness, but not a good choice at all for efficiency (even with Akka, which performs reasonably well; [AsyncFP](https://github.com/laforge49/Asynchronous-Functional-Programming/wiki) might do the trick, though).  Millions of neurons sounds slow--efficiency is probably a significant concern.  If the neurons have some pretty heavy-duty computations to do themselves, then the communications overhead is no big deal.

If communications is the bottleneck, and you have lots of tiny messages, then you should design a custom data structure to hold the network, and also custom thread-handling that will take advantage of all the processors you have and minimize the amount of locking that you must do.  For example, if you have space, each neuron could hold an array of input values from those neurons linked to it, and it would when calculating its output just read that array directly *with no locking* and the input neurons would just update the values *also with no locking* as they went.  You can then just dump all your neurons into one big pool and have a master distribute them in chunks of, I don't know, maybe ten thousand at a time, each to its own thread.  Scala will work fine for this sort of thing, but expect to do a lot of low-level work yourself, or wait for a really long time for the simulation to finish.

Comment: Well, neuron isn't exactly the right concept, which is why I just say cell, but each cell MUST hold references to several different kinds of connection.  OTOH, the cell isn't currently planned to do much computation.  Mainly responding to messages by adjusting weights.  And, of course, saving it's state at finish, and being loaded at the start.  Threadpools are the obvious alternative, but when I looked at the work that would involve, I started looking for an easier solution.

Comment: @CharlesHixson - Actors are an easier way to use thread pools.  But I really think standard heavyweight messages are too heavy.  Or--figure out what your goal is in terms of messages per second to do something useful, and then check out Akka actor benchmarks.

Comment: @joseph It's not so much "messages/second", at least not from each cell.  But cells send messages to other cells, and each message ripples through the net until it either dies, or causes a new cell to be constructed.  And the rippling isn't just in one direction, it spreads.  So if messages are heavy, I need a different approach.  The speed of Akka may be ok (the benchmark looked impressive), but I'm also worried about RAM consumption.

Comment: The memory overhead of an actor is around 400 bytes, and it looks like your communication pattern would be a good fit for Akka. You might want to spread your cells out as children of a group of parents, though, depending on how frequently cells are created and die. Please ping the mailing-list if you go down this path!

Comment: I would suggest to go with technology you know better - this will allow to quick prototype. Also consider `Erlang` - it can be learned in no time (`Scala` + `Akka` will be considerably harder), prototyping is very fast (actual speed depends on skills), messages throughput is the same. The drawback is calculations (if you have some Hodgkin/Huxley equations or whatever your cells are) and slow IO (save/restore state - actually there are workarounds). For a long-term project, again, I will choose a tool that will give a code, readable in a year or two - e.g. good old `Java`.

Comment: @Rex Kerr Will agree only after I will write my first 1 year-old Scala code ^)    E.g. Scala code is absolutely beautiful

Comment: @idonnie - I can read my I-picked-up-Scala-a-month-ago code with no problem.  It reads like Java, but I can read it fine.  Also, I disagree that picking up Erlang is faster.  Scala was easier for me (though the learning curve is longer for Scala, I'll agree).

Comment: @ Rex Kerr OP could try to learn both languages, and then tell us.